# Automatically including defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

**Background**

I know that

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

at the top of each view is important, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to automatically include it in every view or if there was a way to do away with it completely?

I know that .htaccess is used to prevent direct access is this not sufficient enough in terms of protection or is:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Necessary for every single view?

This isnt a vital issue but its nice to make things DRY and not having to put the same line of code at the top of every view.

I have looked on stack for similar posts but they all seem to be just about explaining what the definition is for (which I know but not well enough to know if i can do without it or replace it with a more automatic version).

Comment: " .htaccess is used to prevent direct access is this not sufficient enough in terms of protection" - Yes, it would be. This would also naturally return a 403 Forbidden status (as opposed to 200 OK), so will keep it out of the search engines.

Comment: Thats ok this project is for inhouse use only and cant be accessed outside our internal network unless your IP is authenticated. So im not so worried about external intrusion. Its more of a just wondering sort of thing in the event I decide to make a public facing app. I think the answer I posted below works rather well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need that code in view files. I know it feels like a security measure, but it is not. Its main purpose is a sanity check. Many (most? all?) of CodeIgniter's core files should not be expected to function properly if used outside of the CodeIgniter framework.

You'd be amazed at how many people try to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my own answer, I'm using a static header and footer, and I can just include

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

just after the body tag, which is included in every view I create.

Got to love static headers and views!